# Delete if condition met in a column

Tags: php, mysql, bash

i have a table like this:

```
id, senderNumber, blacklist
-----------------------------
1   0835636326   Y
2   0373562343   Y
3   0273646833   Y
```

and I want to delete automatically if a new inserted row on another table consist anything on senderNumber column above using a BASH Script

I already using this script:

```
BLOCKLIST="$( mysql -uroot -pabcde smsd -N -s -r -e "SELECT senderNumber FROM blacklist WHERE senderBlock='Y'" | tr '\n' ' ')"
mysql -uroot -pabcde smsd -e "DELETE FROM inbox WHERE senderNumber = '$BLOCKLIST'"
```

and this the output:

```
    sh -x /etc/autodelete.sh
+ tr \n  
+ mysql -uroot -pabcde smsd -N -s -r -e SELECT senderNumber FROM blacklist WHERE senderBlock='Y'
+ BLOCKLIST=083808034690 08164853500 
+ mysql -uroot -pabcde smsd -e DELETE FROM inbox WHERE senderNumber = '083808034690 08164853500 '
```

but no luck. any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: LIKE doesn't need a `=`

Comment: And the query doesn't need a `LIKE`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  mysql -uroot -pabcde smsd -e "DELETE FROM inbox WHERE senderNumber like =".$BLOCKLIST
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete a number of records by just glueing the `senderNumber` in a list. In fact, you could delete these records in one query:

```
DELETE FROM inbox LEFT JOIN blacklist USING (senderNumber) WHERE blacklist.senderBlock='Y'
```

(note that this is untested)

Another way to do it, is to use `IN`:

```
DELETE FROM inbox WHERE senderNumber IN ('083808034690','08164853500')
```

but you'll have to find a way to add the comma.

Comment: i just need to delete one record but the condition are must met from inside the senderNumber column. yes you're right, using IN.